# Interpretation of feature contribution in random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, interpretation

In the [featureContribution](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/rfFC/man/featureContributions.html) function (in the `R` package [`rfFC`](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/rfFC/)), what should we interpret if all the scores for all the features are negative? For example, if there were 7 features and after running the `featureContribution` function we got feature values as:

```
fc = c(-0.031544542, -0.064272583, -0.02307187, -0.000213402, -0.040743263, 
       -0.042137713, -0.080828973)
```

Then what is the final interpretation? *Is it something like all the features are not contributing to the prediction for this data point?*

The github code for the package can be found [here](https://github.com/rforge/rffc/tree/master/pkg/R).

Please find a reproducible example to work with below

```
# # randomForest - For random forest model
library(randomForest) 
# # rfFc - For feature contribution
library(rfFC)

set.seed(294056)

# # Read input data
df = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kartheekpnsn/MyScripts/master/Files/input.csv")
# # Remove this column
df = df[-8]
# # Remove status column
df$Status = NULL

# # Master data 1-7 columns and Anomaly column
mydf = cbind(df[,1:7], df["Anomaly"])
rm(df)
# # Make Anomaly column as factor
mydf[,8] = as.factor(mydf[,8])
# # Change the name of Anomaly column to Status (not necessary)
colnames(mydf)[8] = "Status"
# # X: predictors
X <- mydf[, 1:(ncol(mydf) - 1)]
# # target: class
target <- mydf[,"Status"]

# # Build the model
rF_Model <- randomForest(x=X, y=as.factor(as.character(target)), ntree=500, importance=TRUE, keep.inbag=TRUE, replace=FALSE) 

li <- getLocalIncrements(rF_Model,X)
fc<-featureContributions(rF_Model, li, X)
fc = as.data.frame(fc)


# # Data where the fc score is all negative
output = cbind(fc[apply(fc, 1, function(x) all(x < 0)),], mydf[apply(fc, 1, function(x) all(x < 0)),])
print(fc[apply(fc, 1, function(x) all(x < 0)),])
print(output)
```

Comment: It would help if you could add some more context here, such as a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: (To whom it may concern, note that how to interpret statistical output is generally on topic here.)

Comment: Thanks @gung. I have added an example in the question (edited).

Comment: Please paste the reproducible example into your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: @KartheekPalepu is there anyway to still download this package?

Comment: @RTrain3K Please use `install.packages("rfFC", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Answer (score 2):

> Unlike in the variable importance measures, feature contributions are computed separately for each instance/record and
>   provide detailed information about relationships between
>   variables and the predicted value: the extent and the kind
>   of influence (positive/negative) of a given variable.

For more reference please see [Interpreting random forest models using a feature contribution method](http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/79159/1/feature_contribution_camera_ready.pdf)

The paper can be also found in the describtion of the function from the linked package in the question post.

Comment: So accordingly should we be considering the absolute value instead of considering the signed value as the Feature Contribution score?